# What is the formula for coxph.detail$hazard?

Tags: r

I have been trying to determine the formula used in `coxph.detail(fit)$hazard`. It is not clear to me how it is computed from the `coxph.detail` doc:

> "the hazard increment. Note that the hazard and variance of the hazard are always for some particular future subject. This routine uses object$mean as the future subject."

Comment: Which R package? `survival` ?

Comment: If so, then you can always view the actual code via `functionBody(survival::coxph.detail)`

Comment: Calling functionBody(survival::coxph.detail) does not show how its computed, because a C function is called to compute it.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to avoid lengthy comments. From `functionBody(survival::coxph.detail)` you'll see that it's calling `Ccoxdetail`:

```
 ff <- .C(Ccoxdetail, ...
```

and then you look at the package source, available at

https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/survival_2.41-3.tar.gz

unzip and untar to find a file `survival\src\coxdetail.c`

(not pasting the entire code to avoid duplication).

More importantly, if you look at the vignette, you'll see two references that are worth reading:

> Andersen, P. and Gill, R. (1982). Cox’s regression model for counting processes, a large sample study. Annals of Statistics 10, 1100-1120.
>
> Therneau, T., Grambsch, P., Modeling Survival Data: Extending the Cox Model. Springer-Verlag,
> 2000.

Answer (score 0):

For ties="breslow", coxph.detail(fit)$hazard is the number of events at time t divided by the sum of exp(fit$linear.predictors), where the sum is over the subjects at risk. Note that fit$linear.predictors are CENTERED.